# Find the closest bar, when searching for a drink

Tags: mysql, performance, spatial, query-performance

Problem: Find the closest bar that serves the drink(s) I'm looking for.

[image]

Here you can find the generated MySQL code http://pastebin.com/5Uc2ewUW

The API Request that interacts with this problem will have these parameters

```
query, String, ideally the drink name 
lng, double, the starting longitude
lat, double, the starting latitude
range, integer, max distance in meters (with a default value)
```

The query parameter may select more than one drink (think about searching for "Vodka").

What would be a good strategy to write a SQL query with good performance?

I'm not very expert, but my idea is to

- SELECT bars in the range
- SELECT from drink__bars where bar_id is in the previous select result
- JOIN the drinks table to get drinks data

How do I set the order based on the distance?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: You should just find the nearest bar and order whatever drinks they serve.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'd like to let people consume what they like within the minimum walking distance possible.

Comment: @leorossi MySQL has some particularities regarding spatial data, which may make these queries relatively slow (depending on the number of bars). Check if that is a problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
set @x = 15;
set @y = 25;

select sqrt(pow(b.lat-@y,2) + pow(b.lng-@x,2)) as distance,  b.name, d.name
from `drinks` d
 join `drink__bars` db on d.id = db.drink_id
 join  `bars` b on b.id = db.bar_id
where d.`name` = 'Beer'
order by distance asc;
```

Full [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b2ccf/13), with some data. Use your preferred distance function to replace the plain one I used.

I would recommend against having `Id` on many-to-many relations. And prefer NOT NULL always, unless you have a very strong case to allow NULLs (you don't).

Answer (score 0):

Start with a function to calculate de distance between 2 points

```
calculate_distance_function(start_lat,start_lng,end_lat,end_lng)
```

and a query like

```
declare 
    @start_lat float,
    @start_lng;

select
    b.name, 
    MIN(calculate_distance_function(@start_lat,@start_lng,b.lat,b.lng) Distance
from bars b
left join drink_bars db on
    b.id = db.bar_id
left join drinks d on
    d.id = db.drink_id
group by
    b.name
order by
    Distance ASC
LIMIT 1
```

should do the trick.

Edit:

```
declare 
    @start_lat float,
    @start_lng;

select
    b.name bar_name,
    d.name drink_name,
    calculate_distance_function(@start_lat,@start_lng,b.lat,b.lng) distance
from bars b
left join drink_bars db on
    b.id = db.bar_id
left join drinks d on
    d.id = db.drink_id
order by
    Distance ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Probably is not clear, but I'm looking for *drink* names, ordered by *bar distance*.

Comment: the edit query should be what you need